# Ctrl + F5 breaks appcache in Firefox(35)

Tags: firefox, caching, html5-appcache

I'm using appcache to store a web app offline...it works fine.

When I'm in Firefox, if I use Ctrl + F5 to force a refresh on a page that has been cached, it resets that page to zero bytes. That page is therefore lost until the manifest file is updated.

This behaviour occurs if I'm online or offline.

Doing it on the index page results in that page reporting that Firefox is in offline mode when that page is refreshed with plain F5 (though the browser isn't offline, but that's presumably a reaction to a zero bytes index.html file or any file).

If I'm online, Ctrl + F5 will load the page, presumably from the server, but does not restore the file that is in the cache at zero bytes.

Any ordinary refreshing (just F5), online or offline, calls on the empty file locally and simply results in the message: "Firefox is currently in offline mode and can't browse the Web"

I've tried searching for this issue and can't see that it's an issue for anyone else.

I could put out an alert - "Do not force refresh this file in Firefox", but I'd rather it didn't behave this way.

Further search: This is a bug that will be fixed in Firefox 36
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1095281

But not everyone necessarily keeps up to date, even with evergreen browswers, so question still stands.

How do I stop Ctrl + F5 breaking appcache in Firefox?